# jQuery .addclass not working in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I have the following `div` and it shows a sticky header using `<div id="header-sticky-wrapper" class="sticky-wrapper is-sticky" style="height: 205px;">`

How could I append another class to this line?

I am using the following but its not working but I have run it in the console and it gives me my answer I am wanting - WP has JQ loaded as there are other plugins etc that are working fine:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#header-sticky-wrapper').addClass( 'nonHomeLogo' );
});
```

Comment: Check the console for errors.

Comment: are you having error?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
$('#header-sticky-wrapper').addClass( 'nonHomeLogo' );
});` why not use like this?

Comment: @guradio WP has no conflict on by default

Comment: So does the header get loaded dynamically? `console.log($('#header-sticky-wrapper').length);`

Comment: @Musa yeah i guess so maybe there are other errors in JS that is why it is not working because as far as i can see the code should work

Comment: @epascarello Yes it does but I have set my code in the header of my "dynamic" file

Comment: @epascarello he has wrap his code in `document.ready` i think is should be sufficient enough even if it is dynamically added?

Comment: Is the `nonHomeLogo` class correctly formatted?

Comment: No, if the header is added after ready it will not be found. It is like not being home when your phone rings. You are not going to hear it to answer it. If ready has fired, the code inside is just going to run when evaluated.

Comment: How can you use event delegation when there is no event to listen for?

Comment: @JessMcKenzie How is the header file getting loaded.

Comment: @epascarello Via PHP

Comment: then just add the script just before the `</body>` @JessMcKenzie

Comment: @guradio its currently in the <head> so it should be working

Comment: So does the console.log line show anything?

Comment: This comment thread might be getting a bit too long(just suggesting chat here).

Comment: What is the value for `console.log($('[id="header-sticky-wrapper"]').length)`???

Comment: So that means it can not find the element. So somehow you need to wait until the element is there. Not knowing HOW th header is actually loaded is making it hard to give you an answer. It could also be the id you are looking for is not there when the ready is called and that is causing it not to load.

Comment: So, that is the issue. There is no element present at the time execution happens. You'll need to find the code which adds the header.

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready()` and `$(window).load()` fire only once when the `DOM` is ready and when the page first loads respectively. Using it in a script that will be loaded dynamically has no effect.

You can set a timeout to execute your script

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#header-sticky-wrapper').addClass( 'nonHomeLogo' );
}, 1000);
```

Which is not guaranteed to be executed before your `#header-sticky-wrapper` enters the `DOM`

If the new content is put into the `DOM` via the `jQuery.load()` function, `jQuery` will execute any script that exists it that content. In that case, you could add your script somewhere after the element in question.

```
<div id="header-sticky-wrapper">...</div>
<script> $('#header-sticky-wrapper').addClass( 'nonHomeLogo' );</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code:

```
 (function($) {
    $('#header-sticky-wrapper').addClass( 'nonHomeLogo' );
    })(jQuery)
```

Comment: really interested why I have negative feedback :))  There can be a situation, that in moment when author tries to add his code - that ready event was triggered before this moment, so his code will never work. My code is not depends on "ready" event

Comment: Didn't vote on this answer, but I'm guessing because its a code dump that doesn't explain why the OP should use the code presented, or what it does for that matter.

Comment: If the element does not exist when ready is there, how would running it right away fix it?

Comment: @epascarello, in my code there is no .ready event. It is just an self-executing function, that not depends on .ready event.

Comment: @Daedalus, I know that it is "dirty" code but we don't have enought information from author.

Comment: @DenysKonoplin My point is your code isn't explained; its just 'try this' with no rhyme or reason.  And usually, the correct course of action when not having enough information is to 'wait'.

Comment: @Daedalus, well, at least in case of my answer was correct - then we could understood the origin of problem

Comment: @DenysKonoplin And _why_ is it correct, in this instance?

Comment: @Daedalus I wrote about it at start of this strange dialog

Comment: @DenysKonoplin Add it to your answer then, and in greater detail.